# Array has garbage values in function in c++!

Tags: c++, arrays, garbage

I have the following function:

```
  int *array1=new int [3];
  void My_function()
  {
  My_set(array1);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){    //The output is 5 15 55
  cout<<array1[i]<<endl;
  }
  Display (array1)

  }

  void My_set(int *array1)
  {
  array1[0]=5;
  array1[1]=15;
  array1[2]=55;
   }

  void Display(int *array1){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  cout<<array1[i]<<endl; //The output is Garbage  -842150451
   }

   }
```

Note: This problem occurred in complex project but I show my problem in simple code ! 
THANK YOU :)

Comment: Works for me http://ideone.com/GBkVTo...

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` and it will warn you when you overflow the buffer in most debug compilers.

Comment: @awesomeyi: That code you compiled has undefined behavior. So it's irrelevant that it does what you expected it to do.

Comment: try int *array1 = new int[3];

Comment: Generally use of raw pointers is not a good idea. In your case where number of elements is already known use 'std::array' (e.g., 'std::array<int, 3> array1').

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your array like this `int *array1 = new int[3];`

Comment: Definitely, I was wondering why he/she was declaring it with new. Figured for testing? Dan brought up a good point though. @user3316887 if you end up creating your array with a dynamic size, make sure to pass the size of the array as an argument to your functions.